# Why is the content on this Web page overflowing - css help needed

Tags: css

I have a blog and on some posts when viewed on mobile, the content overflows beyond the visible screen. I'm the example below, this is partly caused by the YouTube embedded video being wider than the screen however with the right css tweaks we should be able to force the content to fit the screen.

Please help!

https://www.kalimukti.com/blog/sun-salutation-sequence-should-you-use-up-dog-or-cobra

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this CSS rule (in a media query) should fix that problem:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

It keeps the embedded videos within the screen width and everything else follows accordingly.

Or you could use `max-width: 100%` instead of `width` in there, which is a bit more flexible.